# How to design a Web application in django for mobile devices (phones / tablets)

Tags: django, mobile

Is it possible to analyse the clients browser and serve a special designed layout for mobile devices?

In addition how to implement some fancy widgets usable on mobile-devices like "dropdown" and other things like date/time choices and so on? Not to forget the Style and art of whiping from one sceen to the next in smartphone or tablet way - How goes that?

I'm new on this kind of app/web - development, so any hint would be fine.

**Conclusion so far: Use a Responsive Webdesign like bootstrap to address issues concernig small screens and changing aspect ratios and something like jQuery as Toolbox for Widgets.**

The concrete question now ist how to implement all this into a 0815 'django app'?

Comment: You want to start by looking up Responsive Web.  That will give you a good start.

Comment: Thx, there are the Less Framework and a CSS-Idea named Frameless. Reading down the sites there comes The Golden Grid System. i am a kind of overwhelmed... and Django works with any of them?

Comment: Not found some widgets for choosing one or several entries from a list. e.g. to tag a photo from a list of predefined categories...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to give a chance to Twitter Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/
It's becoming more and more popular when it comes to development of responsive web sites.
They recently realeased new version (Bootstrap 3) which is really great and it helps you to easily control what and how to disply on specific screen size.

If you want to learn more about it you could also visit this youtube channel http://www.youtube.com/user/CodersGuide?feature=watch

Comment: Do you have any good examples for use of bootstrap with django - or at least any hints?

Comment: Well, I use bootstrap with django for most of my projects but there's no difference of using bootstrap with django or some other framework. You use bootstrap just as a frontend framework.
If you want it to integrate it with django more easily maybe this could help you https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit although I didn't use it yet. You may also check this https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3 

Most of new websites use bootstrap for their design, you can find some examples of websites built with bootstrap here http://builtwithbootstrap.com/

Comment: Thx a lot i have to check these hints out.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can certainly make a list of common browser strings and create custom layouts for browsers most common on Android/iOS and serve those directly. (not preferred)

However the generally preferred method is to use CSS media queries for responsive web. These queries look something like:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:321px)
{
    ...
}

@media screen and (min-width:769px)
{
    ...
}

@media screen and (min-width:1025px)
{
    ...
}
```

And in those locations where it says `...` you can do custom classes/positioning/styling for all your elements. But Google is your friend in finding good tutorials for these.

Also there are many CSS/JavaScript libraries out there to create good buttons/layouts for mobile devices. These libraries often take into account that the touch areas for buttons need to be larger then the visible area, that there is enough spacing between elements. Often they also include "mobile" widgets, e.g. fancy dialog selectors that pop open and look just like the native popups on iOS or Android. Once again Google will be your friend.

If however you find yourself forced to do browser string comparisons don't expect your guess at the device to be correct. Browser strings are quite tricky and don't reveal a lot of information of the device. E.g. you may have no idea if the visitor is using Chrome for Android on a tablet or a smartphone. You can use browser strings to determine if the user is on Android or iOS for instance. But for Android don't expect to be able to identify all possible screensizes/devices on the market from the browserstrings.

Comment: That would help for most cases, yes. However as explained above merely identifying that the user is using a phone or tablet will not yet give you the actual size of the screen. That is where CSS and media queries come in. Although it depends entirely on the type of design you're planning to create.

Comment: This Responsive Web thing - is this not the better way? What's the difference?

Comment: Responsive Web, as used in Bootstrap, is most dynamic. However sometimes you want a completely custom design for mobile devices. E.g. only with 10 items per page instead of 50 or something like that. In that case user agent recognition can help you. But for the markup itself responsive web is probably the best way because it takes least time. And you can still combine it. Use user agent recognition to limit the number of results and Bootstrap for the display.

Comment: I'm with you, Responsive Web doesn't make a good mobile design for free.